# jQuery UI Datepicker Rangeselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know from their documentation, that there is the ability to use a single input field for a range selection.

How can this be achieved? I have tried the code that was suggested in ***jQuery UI 1.6 - The User Interface Library for jQuery*** , but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
$(function(){     
       //create config object
       var pickerOpts = {
         rangeSelect: true,
         rangeSeparator: " to "
      };     
        //create the date picker
        $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts); 
      });
```

What happens, is, that it just selects ONE date, not allowing for the range selection, I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As previous poster said, rangeSelect option was eliminated. However, the calendar widget whose rangeSelect option JQuery derived from is still available here:

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range

Answer (score 8):

Here is an idea on how to solve it using only jquery ui and one datepicker.

```
    $("#date").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        if(!$(this).data().datepicker.first){
            $(this).data().datepicker.inline = true
            $(this).data().datepicker.first = selectedDate;
        }else{
            if(selectedDate > $(this).data().datepicker.first){
                $(this).val($(this).data().datepicker.first+" - "+selectedDate);
            }else{
                $(this).val(selectedDate+" - "+$(this).data().datepicker.first);
            }
            $(this).data().datepicker.inline = false;
        }
    },
    onClose:function(){
        delete $(this).data().datepicker.first;
        $(this).data().datepicker.inline = false;
    }
})
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3FrL/3/

Comment: I see that there may be a feature deprecation here in a future version of JQuery UI but I did make this solution above work for me using datepicker v 1.9.2 and its exactly what I needed!  I'm willing to use this solution now with the notion that it may break upon a future upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

The range feature has been removed in the latest version of jQuery! The datepicker plugin [is being refactored](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137778/Datepicker), but as one of the [jQuery team members says](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/a1ff345a8ba99c51):

> The plugin was refactored to simplify
>   it. There are plans to further 
>   refactor it in the future. The date
>   range functionality is planned, but as
>   a  separate plugin that will reuse the
>   Datepicker plugin.

Comment: Ok, I removed the links. Those weren't my sites, anyhow, so I have no control over them.

Answer (score 1):

> I know from their documentation, that there is the ability to use a single input field for a range selection.

This can be achieved using the [DatePick.js](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range) plugin, available for [download here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html).

> Here is something that should help...

Source : [**Select Date Range using Datepick.js**](http://yassershaikh.com/select-date-range-using-jquery-datepicker-js-and-datepick-js/)

[[Demo on Jsfiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/5FWaN/) [[Demo on Datepick.js Website]](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range)

**Html:**

```
<h2>Select date range using datepick.js</h2>

<p>
    <span class="demoLabel">Date range:</span>
    <input type="text" id="rangePicker" size="20" />
</p>

<p id="selectedDates">
</p>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#rangePicker').datepick({ 
        rangeSelect: true,
        onClose:function(dates) {        
            setSelectedDateRange(dates);
        }
    });

    function setSelectedDateRange(dates){
        var startDate = "start date = " + dates[0];
        var endDate = "end date = " + dates[1];

        $("#selectedDates").html(startDate + "<br/>" + endDate);
    }
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could also checkout the functionality available at 
http://stephencelis.github.io/timeframe/

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I can find, but haven't looked at the exact implementation details.

Once you click the input box, select "date range", which is the last option.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/

Comment: That is good and all, but what about customization? I need to be able to set various options to the range selector, for an example, once I select the first date, the second can't be less than the 1st one.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like it supports that. :-/  To the best of my knowledge, the only range related to a single base JQuery UI date picker is the "allowable" range, meaning you can only select a date within that given range.

Comment: It appears, that I will just use 2 input boxes. However, I would like to know, if this feature has been removed? Because I've seen it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have also created nice jquery plugin. It can be used in any scripting language. It supports from and to date selection.
Please refer below link.
http://webtech-training.blogspot.in/2010/09/jquery-date-range-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Victor's awnser. I also added some code to highlight the selected dates and added as small delay in hiding the calendar.

```
    $("#period").datepicker({ 
        minDate: "+2D", 
        maxDate: "+1Y",
        dateFormat : "mm-dd-yy",    
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showAnim : "fadeIn",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {

            if(!$(this).data().datepicker.first){
                $(this).data().datepicker.inline = true
                $(this).data().datepicker.first = selectedDate;
                $(this).data().datepicker.s_first = selectedDate;
                delete $(this).data().datepicker.s_second;
            }else{
                if(selectedDate > $(this).data().datepicker.first){
                    $(this).data().datepicker.s_second = selectedDate;
                    $(this).data().datepicker.s_first = $(this).data().datepicker.first;
                    $(this).val($(this).data().datepicker.first+" - "+selectedDate);
                }else{
                    $(this).val(selectedDate+" - "+$(this).data().datepicker.first);
                    $(this).data().datepicker.s_second = $(this).data().datepicker.first;
                    $(this).data().datepicker.s_first = selectedDate;
                }
                $(this).data().datepicker.inline = true;

                var $this = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $this.datepicker("hide");
                    $this.data().datepicker.inline = false;
                },750)
            }
            $(this).datepicker("show"); // update the dates

        },
        onClose:function(){

            delete $(this).data().datepicker.first;             
            $(this).data().datepicker.inline = false;
            $(this).blur()

        },  beforeShowDay: function (date) {

            var d = date.getTime();
            var d_str = date.toJSON().slice(0,10);

            s1 = $(this).data().datepicker.s_first;
            if (s1){
                var d1 = new Date(new String(s1).replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'), "/"));
                var d1_str = d1.toJSON().slice(0,10);
                var d1 = d1.getTime();
            }

            s2 = $(this).data().datepicker.s_second
            if (s2){
                var d2 = new Date(new String(s2).replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'), "/"));
                var d2_str = d2.toJSON().slice(0,10);
                var d2 = d2.getTime();
            }

            if (d_str == d1_str || d_str == d2_str) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
            }else if (d >  d1 && d < d2) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-highlight', ''];
            } else {
                return [true, ''];
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sjaak Wish's answer:
You can't reliably compare date string representation, you need to convert to date object first:
if(new Date(selectedDate) > new Date($(this).data().datepicker.first))